What does this.bind('string') do?
Reading a piece of TypeScript (context Angular) came across a perplexing usage of the JavaScript bind function. Can anyone explain this pattern?
Example 1
const f = this.bind('astring');
return f ? f(someArgs) : someDefaultReturn;

The pattern in the first line is used a number of times here.
Per the docs, the usage for bind says it's called on a function and is passed an object like so:
Example 2
const f = someFunc.bind(someObject);

Where f is a function that calls someFunc and makes its 'this' context equal to someObject when f is called, which all makes sense.
But when the code in the pattern in example 1 at the top is run, someFunc ('this') turns out to be an object (actually an instance of a class which has 'bind' so yes, it may technically be a function) and someObject ('astring') is a primitive not an object (yes, I know all primatives are actually wrapped in objects). It's completely thrown me.
What is this code doing and how?

That's not the same bind method - https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/f271021e190ede70bfd181d46f0a468a8e7fa144/packages/misc/angular-in-memory-web-api/src/backend-service.ts#L192-L198

Thanks - I know that now - not ideal to reuse names in this fashion.

In the first example, the bind method that is being called is a method inside the BackendService class:
protected bind<T extends Function>(methodName: string) {
    const fn = (this.inMemDbService as any)[methodName];
    return fn ? (fn.bind(this.inMemDbService) as T) : undefined;
}

As you can see, this internal bind method searches for the methodName inside the inMemDbService object, and binds the method with the object.

Thankyou. Hadn't thought of stepping into that function under debug as it had the same name as the native Function.prototype.bind. So helpful to collide with names used in standard js - not.
